# How to create a flat Table

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there any function to directly create a flat list of expressions as a function of multiple index variables, in other words a flat version of Table. What I mean is to have for example

```
flatTable[expr[a,b],{a,1,3},{b,7,8}]
```

output a list

`{expr[1,7],expr[1,8],expr[2,7],expr[2,8],expr[3,7],expr[3,8]}`

(or perhaps in a different order). Note that `expr[i,j]` could be a `List` (or a list of lists etc).

One solution seems to be:

```
flatTable[expr_,indices__]:=Flatten[#,{Range[Length[{indices}]]}]&@Table[expr,indices]
```

but there must be a better way.

Comment: Look at [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html). For instance, `expr @@@ Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8}}]`.

Comment: `flatTable = Join @@ Table[##] &`?

Comment: Probably the shortest version: `Flatten@*Table`

Comment: @Wjx, what did you mean with the star? (If you meant Flatten@Table then it of course does not work if the expression in the table already has a list structure.)

Comment: @Kvothe that is `Composition` ~ which is almost identical to `Flatten[Table[##]]&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[flatTable]
flatTable = Flatten[Table@##, Length[{##2}] - 1] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
flatTable[expr[a, b], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 7, 8}]
```

> {expr[1, 7], expr[1, 8], expr[2, 7], expr[2, 8], expr[3, 7],  expr[3, 8]}

```
flatTable[expr[a, b, c], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 7, 8}, {c, 5, 6}]
```

> {expr[1, 7, 5], expr[1, 7, 6], expr[1, 8, 5], expr[1, 8, 6], 
>        expr[2, 7, 5], expr[2, 7, 6], expr[2, 8, 5], expr[2, 8, 6], 
>        expr[3, 7, 5], expr[3, 7, 6], expr[3, 8, 5], expr[3, 8, 6]}

Comment: thanks. This is basically in the spirit of the solution I included myself. But it is a good lesson to see how I could have written it slightly cleaner / more compact.